# No scheduled commands are ready to run in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to run laravel scheduler, it is working on my local machine but when I push to production and `php artisan schedule:run` it returns

> No scheduled commands are ready to run.

Maybe I miss understanding the whole concept of setting up scheduling in Laravel

this is my crontab: `* * * * * php /var/www/laravel/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [

    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        // update lots once an hour
        $schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\Sync\LotController@dumpLots')->hourly();
        // update auctions once an hour
        $schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\Sync\AuctionsController@dumpAuctions')->hourly();
        // update companies once an hour
        $schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\Sync\CompaniesController@dumpCompanies')->hourly();
        // update models once an hour
        $schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\Sync\ModelsController@dumpModels')->hourly();
        // update bid's result's and date's
        $schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\Sync\BidController@syncAll')->hourly();
        // Update statistics once a day at 00:00
        $schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\Sync\StatsController@dumpStats')->daily();
    }

    /**
     * Register the Closure based commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: The crontab runs that command once every minute. When the time is right, Laravel will execute that call, otherwise it will return the message you got. This is prevent the commands running too often. Edit: The reason you can run it locally is most likely because you use a dev environment there?

Comment: @OptimusCrime but the commands are not executed and I don't have any errors in the error log, how can I make them run?

Comment: You have specified that they should run once an hour, that means that every 1/60 of the times the cronjob is executed, the scripts will run. Most likely at xx:00.  You cronjob is execute, it is just the Laravel calls that are not ran, because the clock is not correct, according to your scheduling settings. The entire point here is that you can call these methods a million times, but it will only run once an hour.

Comment: Thank you. You are 100% right the mistake was in my controllers

Comment: @DmitryMalys if you answered your own question, you can post and accept as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you have not added the timezone in the schedule function.

Below is the example to

```
$schedule->command('tenam:before')
        ->dailyAt('22:28')->timezone('Asia/Kolkata');
```

**Just add the timezone to your functions. It will solve your problem.**